# Let me explain, who I am. Maybe you know me

Tags: riddle

My name is Samie Edwardson, erm, no I don't think this is my name.
I have many many faces. Have you seen some of my personalities? Im pretty sure. They are all completely different. You can decide, which one is facing you. But I'm pretty sure, you are not able to talk to all of them. All these faces, have one heart. This heart is willing to help you, where it is able to. But enough with this deep stuff, let's talk about the olympics. I'm a big fan of them... What do you say? You dont want to talk with someone hiding his name? Ok.

> My name is...

Comment: My name is...Slim Shady?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the answer is

> Stack Exchange ( based on the initials of the given name, S.E.)

As,

> SE has many variants/portals such as PSE, MSE, etc.

Also,

> Many participants provide their thoughts, contribute to the contents of these sites.

About talking to faces

> We can contribute actively at one portal at a time, though can contribute in multiple portals at different times but simultaneously it is not possible.

Helping is possible through

> Meta portals.

Thanks @hexomino, the Olympic connection is

> The points one accumulates and receives accreditation for their contributions( through helpful posts, answers, comments etc.) - in the form of Gold, Silver and Bronze Badges.

Comment: Could the Olympics connection be rot13(tbyq, fvyire naq oebamr)?

Comment: @hexomino- well, nice thought. Let me update the same in my answer.

Comment: My problem with this answer is rot13(Lbh pna or ba zber guna bar fgnpx rkpunatr fvgr ng bapr), which contradicts the "But I'm pretty sure, you are not able to talk to all of them" line.

Answer (score 2):

Is your name

> Briareos, also called  Aegaeon, one of the [Hecatoncheires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecatoncheires)?
> In classic Greek mythology, the Hecatoncheires have a hundred hands and fifty faces, each face with a different personality. However, only one personality or face manifests itself at a time, and they are all connected to the same person, or heart. The nod to olympics make me especially think this is him or one of his brothers.